# Way of changing CSS styles in a running Java app

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm working on JavaFX app that uses CSS styles that are included in file. What i want is to change CSS style after an action happens on button and i wrote some code that changes style of `Button` when i enter/exit it:

```
public void actionMouseEntered() {
    buttonReflex1.getStyleClass().clear();
    buttonReflex1.getStyleClass().add("button_reflex_pressed");
    }
public void actionMouseExited(){
    buttonReflex1.getStyleClass().clear();
    buttonReflex1.getStyleClass().add("button_reflex");
}
```

And here you have my CSS file:

```
.button_reflex{
    -fx-shape: "M 200 *a lot of numbers here* Z";
    -fx-background-color: radial-gradient(focus-angle 360deg, focus-distance 0%, center 50% 50%, radius 70%, reflect, lightblue, aqua 30%, blue);
    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(#e4e000 0%, #ff0000 50%, #e4e000 100%);
}
.button_reflex_pressed{
    -fx-shape: "M 200 *a lot of numbers here* Z";
    -fx-background-color: radial-gradient(focus-angle 360deg, focus-distance 0%, center 50% 50%, radius 70%, reflect, dodgerblue, deepskyblue 30%, darkblue);
    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(#e4e000 0%, #ff0000 50%, #e4e000 100%);
}
```

They differ in a color of buttons.

Code i wrote above **WORKS**, but i think i didn't write it in a good way. Could you tell me if my method of implementing it is correct, or if it isn't, please tell me how can i do it better, because i don't want to learn bad habits.

Comment: You can get better answers in [codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since you wrote a working code and seeking for best practice advice.

Comment: Why use JavaScript at all, when you can do it all in CSS using [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)?

Comment: @200_success That's not a javascript/html question. It's about JavaFX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to change the style class. Changing the style class also is not the way best way to approach this. A `PseudoClass` should be used in this case. Also you should avoid duplicating css properties that do not differ or differ only in colors. Use a rule for both to specify this only once making it easier to modify; in the latter case you can use lookedup colors:

```
private static final PseudoClass MY_HOVER = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("my-hover");

...
buttonReflex1.getStyleClass().setAll("button-reflex");
...

    boolean hovering = ...;
    buttonReflex1.pseudoClassStateChanged(MY_HOVER, hovering);
```

```css
.button-reflex {
    -fx-background-color1: lightblue;
    -fx-background-color2: aqua;
    -fx-background-color3: blue;
    -fx-shape: "M 200 *a lot of numbers here* Z";
    -fx-background-color: radial-gradient(focus-angle 360deg, focus-distance 0%, center 50% 50%, radius 70%, reflect, -fx-background-color1, -fx-background-color2 30%, -fx-background-color3);
    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(#e4e000 0%, #ff0000 50%, #e4e000 100%);
}

.button-reflex:my-hover {
    /* only change colors here; keep the rest */
    -fx-background-color1: dodgerblue;
    -fx-background-color2: deepskyblue;
    -fx-background-color3: darkblue;
}
```

**Note:** The `my-hover` pseudoclass is only used here to demonstrate the general approach. JavaFX `Node`s provide some pseudoclasses by default which should be used instead: `hover`, `pressed`, ect...

See [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide: Node](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i meant.

Answer (score 1):

So first off all yes you can change the CSS while run time.

But you are using it in a wrong way.

So if you have your base CSS class for your Node.
For example:

```
.button {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

and now if you want to have an effect for any JavaFx Event than there are some options like **Hover, Pressed, Focused ...**

```
.button {
   -fx-background-color: red;
}

.button:hover {
   -fx-background-color: blue;
}

.button:pressed{
   -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

JavaFx is than handling everything for you and you dont have to change the style manually.